# Gateway Anti-Virus Alert - WP

Tags: wordpress, menu, cpanel

[image]

As you can see from the image above. I am experiencing some sort of error message but i have no idea what it means.

I am using wordpress 4.1 with a default theme. Every time i tried to add a menu to the menu structure i get the following message:

**Gateway Anti-Virus Alert**
This request is blocked by the Firewall Gateway Anti-Virus
Service. Name: Mailer.S (Trojan)

Things that i have already tried:

1. Using different theme
2. Installing and re-installing wordpress
3. Delete everything and start from beginning

And none of this work!

Please help me.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You probably got infected with malware, and a service running on your hosting is blocking some malicious code. At best you can contact your hosting provider and ask them how to resolve. Malware on a WordPress site is pretty common by using outdated plugins, themes or having insecure rights on folders and files.

It's pretty hard to get rid of, you have to search trough every file to check for malicious code and check every folder for files that shouldn't be there.

Comment: Anyway it started working, i havent done anything to it. LOL thanks

Comment: I wouldn't settle for that in terms of security... but it's your call :)